# Where can I find ArcGIS/ESRI sample graphics?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, graphics

I am looking for sample graphics/pictures that I can use in my program for pinpoints and other markers. Does ArcGIS/ESRI have any that are available to the public? I'm trying to use `PictureMarkerSymbol` and I would like to use a url to the graphic/picture location if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESRI do have a useful [resources page](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/02/03/esri-picture-marker-symbol-generator-for-javascript-developers/) for javascript developers that will generate the JSON needed to embed the marker symbol.
I know you're not looking for the JSON, but if you look at the JSON code, there is a url to the image.  I have not tired this, but you might be able to use that url.

Comment: This works for me, however the site you linked doesn't seem to be working properly anymore (at least for me).This link has a working version though http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/portal_symbols/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have been using for some time icons from [Material Design icons by Google](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) and just love it. Docs are [here](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/).

A sample picture: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/maps/1x_web/ic_directions_bike_black_18dp.png